# Regular expressions to prevent emails with only identical characters

Tags: python, regex, email

I am using regular expressions to detect certain info from a text in Python. I am using the following expression to detect all email addresses:

```
import re
extracted_emails = re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}', text)
```

However, this expression allows emails like this one:

```
xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx
```

How can I edit this expression to prevent emails that only have identical characters other than the `@` and the `.`?

Comment: If you plan to keep the same functionality and just skip the unwelcome matches, you may try `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(?<![a-z0-9])(?!([^@])\1*@\1+\.\1{2,3}\b)[a-z0-9]+[._]?[a-z0-9]+@\w+\.\w{2,3}\b', text)]`

Comment: Your code already ignores *valid* emails. I'm not sure you you want to specifically exclude this specific pattern. For example, people with `+` in their email or anybody with a `.info` TLD  are not counted as correct emails here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `one character other than the @ .`? 1 other character than an @ or a dot?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python, use it to your advantage: fetch all the matches with your expression then filter away those that only contain one unique char except for `.` and `@`:

```py
import re
text = "abc@def.ghi and xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx"
extracted_emails = re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}', text)
print([mail for mail in extracted_emails if len(set(list(mail.replace("@","").replace(".","")))) != 1])
```

Result: `['abc@def.ghi']`.

See [proof](https://tio.run/##ZY1BDoIwEEX3nGLshhKgUVm5IHKPQkiFQZuUQkoTq8azY2EhJr7FZN4k8//4sLdBZ/Ms@3EwFgwGFp2FHIi4NEWLHbveJAjdgvtSuF@YcyTwP0Y0FtsaeyHV5AMMsk7qVihFTchF@tynpyrmJaur86ZFVd5jzvx8HZPsHSaw9EfBaKS2lC9h0A0G1kVq@CuSHSjUdEJLlZwsXa7M4KhEg5QUJCEk2pyt7oFdDocqmucP).